# Devise set different root path per user type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I've created a devise user model. There are 2 types of user:

- customer
- admin

I've accomplished bij creating two 'normal' models: customer and admin. These two models are inheriting from the user model, like so:

```
class Customer < User
```

Does anyone know how I can setup a root path per type of user. I want something like this:

```
authenticated :customer do
  root :to => "customer/dashboard#index"
end

authenticated :admin do
  root :to => "admin/dashboard#index"
end
```

UPDATE:

I've solved the problem:

```
root :to => "pages#home", :constraints => lambda { |request|!request.env['warden'].user}
root :to => 'customer/dashboard#index', :constraints => lambda { |request| request.env['warden'].user.type == 'customer' }
root :to => 'admin/dashboard#index', :constraints => lambda { |request| request.env['warden'].user.type == 'admin' }
```

Comment: Please move your updated answer outside of your question and as an answer instead.

Comment: I cant answer my own question for the first 8 hours...

Answer (score 7):

although an old question, there is no answer and it could be useful for others.

In rails 3.2 (I have never tested it with anything lower) you can do this in your routes.rb file

```
authenticated :admin_user do
  root :to => "admin_main#index"
end
```

then have your normal root route further down.

This however, doesn't seem to work in rails 4 as it gives `Invalid route name, already in use: 'root' (ArgumentError)`(as I have just found out and was searching for a solution when I came across this question), if I figure out a way of doing it in rails 4 I will update my answer

Edit:

Ok so for rails 4 the fix is pretty simple but not so apparent right off the bat. all you need to do is make the second root route a named route by adding an as: like this:

```
authenticated :admin_user do
  root :to => "admin_main#index", as: :admin_root
end
```

this is documented [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2393#issuecomment-17298414) but note that it seems like only a temporary fix and so is subject to change again in the future

Answer (score 3):

What you could do is have a single root path, say `home#index` and in the corresponding controller action perform a redirect depending on their user type.

For instance:

```
def index
  if signed_in?
    if current_user.is_a_customer?
      #redirect to customer root
    elsif current_user.is_a_admin?
      #redirect to admin root
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 1 problem with your approach: the customer root and admin root wil not be at domain.com/. It would become something like domain.com/customer and domain.com/admin

Comment: in that case, you need to move these conditions (is_a_customer? and is_a_admin?) into your root method(common method you required to sue for both types of users) and fetch records as per signed in user

Answer (score 0):

Using [after_sign_in_path_for](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Controllers/Helpers%3aafter_sign_in_path_for) should be appropriate. So add this to your `application_controller.rb`:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  if resource.type == 'customer'
    your_desired_customer_path
  else
    your_desired_admin_path
  end
end
```